# How to increase console font in XGP Prolog

Tags: prolog

I just installed XGP Prolog on my mac osx, and wondered if there is a way to increase the font size on the console -- it's so minute I can't read it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The current XGP build is very old (circa 2010). I think the problem with the font sizing is because of the build being out-of-date. I am hoping to create a new XGP build in the next few months.